# Return text from class without using any brackets (python)

Tags: python

Just curious how to do this, an example is the help() command.
Typing `help` returns `"Type help() for interactive help, or help(object) for help about object."`, and I'd like to do something similar.

I know `@classmethod` removes the need for brackets in the class when using a function within it, but this doesn't seem to work when used in conjunction with `__repr__`.

Here's a quick thing I did, while it works when typing `a()`, I want it to also return the text when typing `a` by itself.

```
class a:
    def __repr__( self ):
        return str( "test" )
print a()
```

Comment: Note that `help` is a callable instance of the class `site._Helper`, not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [metaclass](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation):

```
class mcs(type):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "test - from metaclass"

class a(object):
    __metaclass__ = mcs
    def __repr__(self):
        return "test"

print a    # test - from metaclass
print a()  # test
```

Comment: Ahh thanks a bunch, that works great :)  It does seem a little bit of a hack though, is there no way to do it from within the function?

Comment: No. You need to override `__repr__` for the class of which `a` is an instance, and that is done by using a metaclass other than `type` (as shown here) which defines the appropriate `__repr__`.